# git: How to work on subdirectory

Tags: git

I'm going to migrate our project from svn to git. Now some of the developers work only on a subtree of it. Is it possible in git? To be specific, we one need to be able to:
- checkout a subtree of the trunk, change it and commit the changes
- without seeing the trunk. A person may not even be granted privileges to read any other part of the trunk.

We are not interested in setting up two different projects. Majority of the developers would like to see the trunk as a whole

Is it possible in git? And how to get it?

Let me also clarify, that we will get rid of SVN completely, we will work solely with git. We even don't bother with git-svn..

Best,
Tim

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also consider using [git modules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html), if your project can be structured this way.  It still will be very different from the way svn works.

Answer (score 1):

In git it's not possible to checkout only a part of your project or by SVN means only sub-folder of trunk. This is based on the concept of git, cause you will get the complete history of a project and not only a part of it. So the people have to learn to work with the whole tree...but they can of course only change partial areas of it.